# A class both derives from and its first member has type deriving from the same base class. Is the class standard-layout?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

As far as I know, a property of the standard-layout class is that the address of a standard-layout object is equal to its initial member's. I tested the following code with g++ and clang++, but found that  `Derived3` **is** a standard-layout class and `&d` **is not** equal to `&d.c`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base {};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
  int i;
};

struct Derived3 : Base
{
  Derived1 c;
  int i;
};

int main()
{
  cout << is_standard_layout_v<Derived3> << endl;

  Derived3 d;
  cout << &d << endl;
  cout << &d.c << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: cppreference tells us "A standard-layout class is a class that ... * only one class in the hierarchy has non-static data members". But `std::is_standard_layout_v<Derived3>` returns true. Lets wait until language lawyers wake up :-)

Comment: consider to use the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: @Klaus But isn't here the hierarchy `Base` → `Derived3`? Then, the non-static data members are only in `Derived3`, so the rule you pointed to is satisfied here.

Comment: There is also the issue of only having one sub-object of any given class type - now, are there *two* `Base` class sub-objects? (One from the hierarchy and one from the component `Derived1`.) But IANALL :)

Comment: FWIW, both MSVC and clang-cl (in Visual Studio) on my Windows machine agree that it is a standard-layout type, but they also *both* give the same address in the two outputs.

Comment: @AdrianMole Can you check if the two `Base` objects have different addresses?

Comment: You should add the output you're getting into your question.

Comment: Atually, cppreference even has on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo : `Empty base optimization is required for StandardLayoutTypes in order to maintain the requirement that the pointer to a standard-layout object, converted using reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member, which is why the requirements for a standard layout type include "has all non-static data members declared in the same class (either all in the derived or all in some base)" and "has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member".`

Comment: @KamilCuk But, from the same cppreference page: *Empty base optimization is prohibited if one of the empty base classes is also the type or the base of the type of the first non-static data member, since the two base subobjects of the same type are required to have different addresses within the object representation of the most derived type.*

Comment: Looks like the same problem as what is reported in [GCC bug 91080](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91080).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following the word of [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.prop#3), they are indeed standard-layout types. Going through the points one by one:

> A class S is a standard-layout class if it:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference, [...]

`int` is standard-layout. `Derived1` is standard layout, as we'll see.

> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,

`Base` is empty, so standard-layout.

> - has at most one base class subobject of any given type,

Both `Derived1` and `Derived3` has only a single base `Base`.

> - has all non-static data members and bit-fields in the class and its base classes first declared in the same class, and

Meaning, within an inheritance hierarchy, all data members are declared in the same class. This is clearly true for `Derived1`. This is also true for `Derived3` because `Derived1` is not in the inheritance hierarchy.

To make this point clearer, consider a simpler example

```cpp
struct B {};
struct D1 : B {};
struct D3 : B { D1 c; };
```

Which also runs into the same address problems as in the question, but clearly fulfills this bullet point.

> - has no element of the set M(S) of types as a base class, where for any type X, M(X) is defined as follows.
>   [Note 2: M(X) is the set of the types of all non-base-class subobjects that can be at a zero offset in X. — end note]
>
>   - If X is a non-union class type with no non-static data members, the set M(X) is empty.
>   - If X is a non-union class type with a non-static data member of type X0 that is either of zero size or is the first non-static data member of X (where said member may be an anonymous union), the set M(X) consists of X0 and the elements of M(X0). [...]

Meaning, `M(Derived3)` is the set {`Derived1`, `int`}, none of which is a base class of `Derived3`.

Likewise, `M(Derived1)` is the set {`int`}, which is not a base class of `Derived1`.

---

Being standard-layout means the class and its first data member is [pointer-interconvertible](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.compound#4). To be pedantic, the representation of pointers being different doesn't prove there's a problem, but comparing the results of `reinterpret_cast` does:

```
std::cout << (&d.c == reinterpret_cast<Derived1*>(&d));  // 0 for clang and gcc
```

Thus the compilers are not technically compliant. However, this is an impossible situation: the `Base` subobject in `Derived1` [cannot have the same address](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#10.2) as the `Base` subobject in `Derived3`, which is why the compilers placed `Derived1` at a four byte offset from the start.

Standard-layout classes have a [history](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1813.html) of [defect](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1672.html) reports, and this looks like it should be another one.

Comment: Yeah - impossible. Reading the comment on the Q from @KamilCuk and my follow-on, empty base class optimization is both *required* and *forbidden*. If that's not a defect, then I don't know what is.

Comment: https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2736.html

Comment: @AdrianMole When it gets fixed and propagates into some complex C++ frameworks, I bet you a problem here and there will fix itself, as if by magic. Or will magically appear. That's a nasty language bug. Plenty of style guides prohibit multiple derivation precisely because it was under-specified. Now we get different behavior in a very basic feature between freshly fixed C++ and legacy stuff. This is gonna be fun.